# Общение серверов Django

Tags: python-3.x, django, xml, request, response

Моя задача - настроить общение между двумя серверами. Запросы в формате xml отправляет Django, а внешний сервер принимает их, интерпретирует и отвечает. Решила опробовать код запросов и ответов на двух локальных серверах с django. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как настроить ответы на xml запросы? Может элементарный вопрос, но я пока не нашла ответа. 
Например, отправляем запрос hello -> получаем ответ i'm a cool server -> выводим на странице пользователья "i'm a cool server".

Пока я осилила только генерацию запроса на другой сервер и получение простого ответа 200, 404 (по умолчанию html). Как настроить второй сервер на распознавание запросов и выбор ответов, если от него ничего другого не требуется?

```
class CreateX(CreateView):
form_class=XForm
template_name = 'form.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    send_xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><xrrp><command>hello!</command></xrrp>'
    url = "http://127.0.0.1:7000"
    res=requests.post(url, data=send_xml, headers={'Conetent-Type': 'application/xml'})
    if res.status_code == 200:
        return HttpResponse(res.content, content_type='application/xml')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('ЧТО-ТО НЕ ТО')
```

Comment: Ничего в вопросе не понятно. Как в Django распознавать запросы и отправлять ответы — написано в любом учебнике по Django;  с чем у вас возникли затруднения — неясно. Судя по показанному вами коду, вы уже умеете распознавать запросы и отправлять ответы в Django — что мешает написать аналогичный код для второго сервера?

Comment: да, пока не распознаю ответ

Comment: `res.content` содержит текст ответа второго сервера, делайте с ним что хотите. Вопрос всё ещё непонятен

Comment: Вы хотите создать сервер с API на Django? Возможно, Вам подойдёт django-rest-framework (или django-rest-framework-xml).

Comment: я хотела пойти простым путем (более-менее известным мне), но похоже придется открывать доки реста и знакомиться с ним.

Comment: столкнулась с проблемой, что если подобные запросы отправлять на локальный сервер, то все ок. но если на действующий, то запрос приводит к ошибке "ConnectionError at /form/

('Connection aborted.', BadStatusLine('\x00\x00\x00´<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>\n'))". Совсем запуталась, что так не так.